# Setting max column width for autoSizeColumn with Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

We are using `autoSizeColumn` to autosize each column of each sheet in our workbook.  It works well except that in some cases it yields columns of extremely large widths.  It is not always possible for us to humanly inspect our output to detect such conditions.

Is there a way to realize the following logic in Apache POI?

```
set MAX_COL_WIDTH
enable auto-column-width
LOOP
  IF column-width > MAX_COL_WIDTH
  THEN
    disable auto-column-width for sheet
  ENDIF
  reenable auto-column-width
ENDLOOP
```

Comment: For each column, save current width, auto-size, get new width, if too big revert to old one and skip rest of sheet?

Answer (score 0):

After executing autoSize, set max column width if column is wider:

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }

for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    if (sheet.getColumnWidth(i) > 15000) {
       sheet.setColumnWidth(i, 15000);
    }
}
```